# Angular: Value of my variable doesnt change

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable `name` that has an initial value and will use it later to return a fetched value. During my fetch, I tried to display the new value of my variable using console.log and works properly. But how come, when I try to return my updated variable, it returns its original value which is "initialValue":

```
return function(item) {
        var name = "initialValue";
        InquiryService.searchLocalHeader(item).then(function(result) {  
            name = result[0].name;
            console.log(name);
        })
        return name;
   }
```

Is there a way that I can retain its latest value that I assigned? Thank you!

Comment: why dont you shift your InquiryService call to a angularService and apply filter after that.

Comment: this may help you http://bahmutov.calepin.co/delayed-angularjs-filter-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Your function is calling your service function - `searchLocalHeader` and while the service is busy fetching your data, the function has reached its end and returned the initial value.

One solution might be this:

```
   function myFunc(item) {
        var name = "initialValue";
        InquiryService.searchLocalHeader(item).then(function(result) {  
            name = result[0].name;
            console.log(name);
            return name; // returns latest value
        }, function(error) {
               return name; // in case of error -- returns the initial value
           })

   }
```

Read more about promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I actually tried this awhile ago, placing the return statement inside the then() function, but it only returns nothing. so I need to place my return statement within my very first function, and definitely my problem because it seems that right after it leaves the then(), the value of my variable name goes back to its initial value.

Comment: by the way - why are you returning the main function? It doesn't seem legit

Comment: it is actually inside my filter. here is my whole filter

`.filter("getName", ['InquiryService', function(InquiryService) {
       return function(item) {
        var name = "initialValue";
        InquiryService.searchLocalHeader(item).then(function(result) {  
            name = result[0].name;
            console.log(name);
        })
        return name;
   }
    }]);`

Comment: You tried changing the code like I suggested? do you have the same issue like before?

Comment: yeah I did. and as I said, it doesnt work when my return statement is inside the then() function. I could fetch nothing from my return

Comment: Is there a way that WHILE I am inside the then() function, I could pass the value of name variable in my view?

Comment: the thing is, your function is part of a filter, it has no access to your template scope. It only returns a value.

Comment: you are making asynchronous calls every digest cycle (filters are invoked every cycle), this can cause a major performance issue. How about trying @ismail baig suggestion - move the service call to the controller level

Answer (score 0):

try returning inside the then fucntion. it should be correct value.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.filter('customFilter', ['someService', function (someService) {
  function customFilter(input) {
     // manipulate input with someService
     input += someService.getData(); 
     return input;
  }

  customFilter.$stateful = true; // this line makes it stateful
  return customFilter;
}]);
```

Comment: What if the Promise `InquiryService.searchLocalHeader(item)` is rejected?

Comment: thanks for pointing out, update the answer, but anyhow AranS has the same answer above.

Comment: sadly, doesnt work when i try to put my return statement inside the then() function

Comment: add your filter something line customFilter.$stateful = true;

Answer (score 0):

You need to added $state = true

```
yourServiceName.$stateful = true
return yourServiceName;
```